# belongsToMany -> belongsToMany Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Edit*
Im pretty happy with my DB setup. I want to know the 'Laravel way' to query this data and update it.

Just after a bit of advice on the best way to structure this and update the data! Im working on a platform for nurseries. Children can be assigned to a room each day of the week; either morning, afternoon or full day. I currently have the following (forget the room_child pivot for now)

child Model

| id | name |
| --- | --- |

daysOfWeek Model

| id | day |
| --- | --- |

child_days pivot table

| child_id | day_id |
| --- | --- |

dayType Model

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | full |
| 2 | morn |

days_type pivot

| day_id | type_id |
| --- | --- |

So - Want to be able to book each child in for each day of the week, possibly two different types per day. Morning and evening.

EG
child 1 -

| Monday | Morning |
| --- | --- |
| Tuesday | Full Day |
| Wednesday | Afternoon |

Any advice on best way to do this and how to manage it? As in, can I eager load the results or something?

Comment: Perhaps add another column in the child_days pivot? So it would be child_id, day_id, day_type_id. Here's some info on pivots: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns

Comment: Asking for opinions on design is better suited to Database Administrators site

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an opinion than an answer so take it with a grain of salt.

---

- **I wouldn't use a `daysOfWeek` model/table at all.**

Why bother? You will end up with a database table that will only contain 7 rows and will never need to grow or shrink. `DayType` can stay. Maybe in the future you'll have more types. At least, that's more likely than the definition of a week being changed.

- **This removes the need for the `child_days` and `days_type` pivot tables.**

---

In the end you're left with just 3 models.

1. `Child`
2. `DayType`
3. `Booking` (or however you want to call it. )

The relationships will be as simple as

- `Booking` belongsTo `Child`
- `Booking` belongsTo `DayType`
- `Child` hasMany `Booking`
- `DayType` hasMany `Booking`

---

The `bookings` table I'm imagining has the following columns.

- id `(pk)`
- child_id `(fk)`
- day_type_id `(fk)`
- day (could be `varchar(9)` or `enum('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday')`)

Enum makes a bit more sense. If you use them you might be interested in [Enum Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#enum-casting)

---

Comment: OK, thanks!  Whats the best way to query this then?  Do i use eager loading?

Comment: You can use eager loading, yes. `Child::with('bookings')`